# Exchange Management Shell strip output

Tags: exchange-server-2010, exchange-management-shell

Exchange 2010, I am using the following in the exchange management shell
`$mailidentities = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$_.identity.tostring() -like "* STAFF/*" -and $_.identity.tostring() -NotLike "*Ex_Staff*" -and $_.User.tostring() -like "*SELF*" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | Select-object Identity
foreach ($mailidentity in $mailidentities)
{
     Write-Host "$mailidentity"
}`

The results are returned   `@{Identity=domain/Group/UserName}`
What is the correct syntax to get back only `domain/Group/UserName` ? 
The final outcome is to assign fullaccess permission to a supervisory mailbox to each user.

Answer (score 0):

Add the -ExpandProperty option to the Select cmdlet. `Select-obejct -ExpandProperty Identity` . The shortcut -exp can be used also. 
For syntax of Select or Select-Object cmdlet see http://www.colorconsole.de/PS_Windows/en/Select-Object.htm or https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html